# Spark filter DataFrame by comparing list

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Python on Spark. I want to filter rows where a specified field equals a whole list.

```
df.show()
```

```
+--------------------+---------------+
|                 _id|             a1|
+--------------------+---------------+
|[596d799cbc6ec95d...|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]|
|[596d79a2bc6ec95d...|     [1.0, 2.0]|
+--------------------+---------------+
```

I want result to be

```
+--------------------+---------------+
|                 _id|             a1|
+--------------------+---------------+
|[596d79a2bc6ec95d...|     [1.0, 2.0]|
+--------------------+---------------+
```

I use this

```
df.filter(df.a1 == [1., 2.])
```

But it failed.

Traceback

```
  File "/Users/gzc/Documents/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o129.equalTo.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [1, 2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.$eq$eq$eq(Column.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.equalTo(Column.scala:290)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: what is your filter condition? do you want to  filter out row with a1 =  [1.0, 2.0] ?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala Yes, I want rows which `a1 == [1.0, 2.0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a literal `array` as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, lit

df = sc.parallelize([(1, [1., 2.]), (2, [1., 2., 3.])]).toDF(["id", "a1"])
df.where(df.a1 == array(*(lit(x) for x in [1., 2.]))).show()
```

```
+---+----------+
| id|        a1|
+---+----------+
|  1|[1.0, 2.0]|
+---+----------+
```

Comment: This is what I want. Although it's more complicated than what I expected.