# Using ORACLE-LIKE like feature between Spark DataFrame and a List of words - Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My requirement is similar to one in :
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157340/spark-filter-dataframe-by-comparing-list)

Instead of direct match I need LIKE type match on a list. i.e Want to **LIKE** match **COMMENTS** with **List**

```
ID,COMMENTS
1,bad is he
2,hell thats good
3,sick !thats hell
4,That was good

List = ('good','horrible','hell')
```

I want to get output like

```
    ID, COMMENTS,MATCHED_WORD,NUM_OF_MATCHES
    1,bad is he,,
    2,hell thats good,(hell,good),2
    3,sick !thats hell,hell,1
    4,That was good,good,1
```

In simpler terms I need : ( rlike isn't matching values from a list instead expects one single string , as far I know it)

```
file.select($"COMMENTS",$"ID").filter($"COMMENTS".rlike(List_ :_*)).show()
```

I tried isin , that works but matches WHOLE WORDS ONLY.

```
file.select($"COMMENTS",$"ID").filter($"COMMENTS".isin(List_ :_*)).show()
```

Kindly help or please re-direct to me any links as I tried lot of searching !

Answer (score 1):

With simple words I'd use an alternative:

```
val xs = Seq("good", "horrible", "hell")
df.filter($"COMMENTS".rlike(xs.mkString("|"))
```

otherwise:

```
df.filter(xs.foldLeft(lit(false))((acc, x) => acc || $"COMMENTS".rlike(x)))
```

Comment: This works , But few words like "expected" matches word like "unexpected" as rlike is used. Any alternatives to match whole word ? Thanks for that sample above. that works for most of cases !